# lspci | grep Network response

Tags: networking

I do not have wired connection,although everything looks fine.

```
lspci | grep Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller:Real tek Semiconductor Co,....
```

But

```
lspci | grep Network
```

no response.

Why is network not recognized?

Comment: Nothing is not being recognized, it's just a matter of the pattern you are giving `grep` to look for. Run `lspci` and check yourself the output, you will most likely find what you are looking for.

Comment: Or you can try with this one `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @M.Becerra The same,no response.

Comment: The `lspci` listing doesn't specifically contain the word Network nor, of course, Net. There is nothing unusual or wrong about that. I suggest that you start your own new question and describe your ethernet issue.

Comment: @M.Becerra I think you will get a better response with: `lspci -nnk | grep -i Net` or even: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`